# I want PDF file print into network print

Tags: c#

I want PDF file print into network print 
Following code where used, it work fine in local host (development area) but not worked in IIS serve host
Can given to any rights issue? How to solve the issue ?

```
private void SendToPrinter()    
{        
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
info.Verb = "print";    
info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";  
info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;    
Process p = new Process();    
p.StartInfo = info;  
p.Start();       
p.WaitForInputIdle();      
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);    
if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())        
p.Kill(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an authorization/security problem.
IIS (the server) runs in a context which doesn't have access to the shared printer. 
Your local host has it cause it's running in your user's context.